# Linq-to-SQL ToDictionary()

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

How do I properly convert two columns from SQL (2008) using Linq into a `Dictionary` (for caching)?

I currently loop through the `IQueryable` b/c I can't get the `ToDictionary` method to work. Any ideas?
This works:

```
var query = from p in db.Table
            select p;

Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach (var p in query)
{
    dic.Add(sub.Key, sub.Value);
}
```

What I'd really like to do is something like this, which doesn't seem to work:

```
var dic = (from p in db.Table
             select new {p.Key, p.Value })
            .ToDictionary<string, string>(p => p.Key);
```

But I get this error:

> Cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' to
> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'

Answer (score 132, accepted):

```
var dictionary = db
    .Table
    .Select(p => new { p.Key, p.Value })
    .AsEnumerable()
    .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value)
;
```

Comment: Sorry, I may have not been clear, I've tried thie before, but this creates a Dictionary<string, #Anonymous Type>, not Dictionary<string, string>

Comment: Try `kvp => kvp.Value as string`. The point of the answer was `.AsEnumerable()`.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I figured AsEnumerable was needed, but the ToDictionary call still doesn't work. Both columns are varchars in SQL, so they come back as strings, but I can't figure out how to get it to stuff into a Dic....

Comment: I don't know if this is still relevant, but why is the `AsEnumerable` needed?  For me it works without that too, but probably Linq has already changed (7 years have passed)

Comment: @AlexanderDerck - At the time, the `AsEnumerable` was necessary. I don't remember precisely why, after all this time, but a possible explanation is that `ToDictionary` was an extension method on `IEnumerable`, but the interface for Linq-to-SQL was not `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 19):

You are only defining the key, but you need to include the value also:

```
var dic = (from p in db.Table
             select new {p.Key, p.Value })
            .ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p=> p.Value);
```

Comment: -1 The error is that the `<string, string>` part makes it use the `public static Dictionary<TKey, TSource> ToDictionary<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer);` overload instead of the `public static Dictionary<TKey, TElement> ToDictionary<TSource, TKey, TElement>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, Func<TSource, TElement> elementSelector);` overload.

Comment: I think it still needs `.AsEnumerable()` before `.ToDictionary()`

Comment: worked perfectly ... finally the one I was looking for

Answer (score 9):

Thanks guys, your answers helped me fix this, should be:

```
var dic = db
        .Table
        .Select(p => new { p.Key, p.Value })
        .AsEnumerable()
        .ToDictionary(k=> k.Key, v => v.Value);
```

Comment: The reason you need AsEnumerable() is because LINQ to SQL doesn't mix local and remote (SQL) processing so this causes the first part to execute on the SQL server and then the final subsequent part to execute locally using LINQ to Objects which can do Dictionarys :)

Comment: Makes sense. Also, the second parameter in ToDictionary needs its own Func arguments, which was tripping me up earlier.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you create an anonymous object for every item in the table just to convert it?

You could simply use something like:
`IDictionary<string, string> dic = db.Table.ToDictionary(row => row.Key, row => row.Value);`
You may need to include an AsEnumerable() call between Table and ToDictionary().
I don't know the exact type of db.Table.

---

Also correct the first sample, your second loop variable is mismatching at declaration and usage.

Comment: Because `ToDictionary` is in-memory. Not creating an anonymous object means all columns are retrieved from the database instead of just the ones you need.

Comment: `ToDictionary` doesn't know about the underlying structure, it just calls the two callbacks for key and value (in this case simple property selecting lambdas), so this `ToDictionary` call should be functionally equivalent to the foreach in the example he provided. As far as I know all of LINQ methods are deferred, meaning callbacks are only called when necessary.

Comment: If you look with SQL Server Profiler, you'll see that with an anonymous object only two columns are selected, and without it all columns are selected.