# Why does ToDictionary<K,V>() generate a compiler error when used with LINQ to SQL?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Following on from this question:

[Linq-to-SQL ToDictionary()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245168/linq-to-sql-todictionary)

I have a table called `Domains`, it has two columns:

`DomainID int`
`DomainName varchar(250)`

I want to return a `Dictionary<int, string>`. When I try either of the following LINQ to SQL code:

```
Dictionary<int, string> dict =
    dbc
    .Domains
    .Select(d => new {d.DomainID, d.DomainName})
    .AsEnumerable()
    .ToDictionary<int, string>(k => k.DomainID, k => k.DomainName);
```

or

```
Dictionary<int, string> dict = 
    (from d in dbc.Domains
      select new { d.DomainID, d.DomainName })
      .AsEnumerable()
      .ToDictionary<int, string>(k => k.DomainID, k => k.DomainName);
```

I get the following compile error:

`Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>'`

The scenario here seems the same as [q245168](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245168/linq-to-sql-todictionary) and should work, am I missing something obvious?

Cheers
Kev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the generic type arguments; the first is the **source**, not the key:

```
Dictionary<int, string> dict = 
(from d in dbc.Domains
  select new { d.DomainID, d.DomainName })
  .AsEnumerable()
  .ToDictionary(k => k.DomainID, k => k.DomainName); // <==== no angles
```

Here, we are using generic type inference to supply the details.

Comment: Aaahh! so obvious now. Appreciated.

Comment: Is the AsEnumerable() needed?