# How to assign the LINQ query values to a another dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, generics, dictionary

How to assign the result of the Linq Query to a dictionary...

```
 public Dictionary<string, Privilege> GetAllPermissionsByGroupId(string groupid)
    {

        string[] Roles = new string[] { "e8b08a45-9cb5-4ac9-8c6c-9dfe4ac23966$Moderator" };

        List<RolePrivilege> RoleList = new List<RolePrivilege>();
        List<Privilege> PrivilegeList = new List<Privilege>();

        Dictionary<string, RolePrivilege> Role = PrivilegeProxy.GetPrivilegesForRoles("744A2BE3-846E-4E4A-9796-DAF9C743E8FF", Roles);
        RoleList = Role.Values.ToList();


        Dictionary<string, Privilege> Privilege = PrivilegeProxy.GetPrivilegesbyModuleIds(new string[] { "Groups" });
        PrivilegeList = Privilege.Values.ToList();

        var identicalQuery = from roles in RoleList
                            join privileges in PrivilegeList on roles.PrivilegeName equals privileges.Name
                           select new { Roles = roles, Privileges = privileges };


        Dictionary<string, Privilege> Result=new Dictionary<string,Privilege>();
         Result=?


         return Result;

    }
```

Comment: Although I have no idea what these tags have to do with the question.

Comment: @Yuriy - i edited those tags in. It's definetely C#, and he's (i assume) attempting to create a `Dictionary<T,TKey>` from that collection/LINQ query. Are those tags not relevant?

Comment: Sorry, but it's still not clear... what's the string in `Dictionary<string, Privilege>`? The role name? That would associate 1 role to 1 Privilege. If you have more than one privilege per role then what you need is a `Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<Privilege>>`...

Comment: actually my goal is i want to compare the two lists in that which which values are common i should load it in the dictionary...

Comment: Why cant you use ToDictionary as suggested here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you code does not illustrate what you desire to put into dictionary. What should be key? String associated with RolePrivilege?

Nevermind, I would recommend work with pairs instead of values in your dictionaries:

```
var Roles = new string[] { "e8b08a45-9cb5-4ac9-8c6c-9dfe4ac23966$Moderator" };
Dictionary<string, RolePrivilege> Role = PrivilegeProxy.GetPrivilegesForRoles("744A2BE3-846E-4E4A-9796-DAF9C743E8FF", Roles);
Dictionary<string, Privilege> Privilege = PrivilegeProxy.GetPrivilegesbyModuleIds(new string[] { "Groups" });

var identicalQuery = from roles in Role
                     join privileges in Privilege on roles.Value.PrivilegeName equals privileges.Value.Name
                     select new { Roles = roles, Privileges = privileges };

Dictionary<string, Privilege> Result = identicalQuery.ToDictionary(_ => _.Roles.Key, _.Privileges.Value);
```

**EDITED**

Okay, let's imagine contents of both dictionaries:

- Role dic = [{"aaa", RolePrivilege1}, {"bbb", RolePrivilege2}, {"ccc", RolePrivilege3}]
- Privilege dic = [{"aaa", Privilege5}, {"bbb", Privilege6}, {"ddd", Privilege7}]

What do you expect as output?
I suppose you want to get next sequense:

- Result = [{"aaa", Privilege5}, {"bbb", Privilege6}]

Correct? If yes, this request will help:

```
        var Result = Role
            .Join(Privilege,
                outer => outer.Key,
                inner => inner.Key,
                (outer, inner) => new { Str = outer.Key, Privilege = inner.Value })
            .ToDictionary(_ => _.Str, _ => _.Privilege);
```

Comment: it is just a dic i should i bind it.......Dictionary<string, Privilege> Result thats all....

Comment: or is ther any option to get the common values in this two dics Role, Privilege.and bind it another dic in  Dictionary<string, Privilege>....

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for [`Enumerable.ToDictionary()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277.aspx), but I can only guess what you're trying to do...

```
var query = from employee in employees
            join privilege in privileges
              on employee.PrivilegeName equals privilege.Name
            select new
            {
                Employee = employee,
                Privilege = privilege
            };

var dictionary = query.ToDictionary(o => o.Employee);
```

Your variables are confusing because `employeeA` is of type `RolePrivilege` and `employeeB` is of type `Privilege`. Also, it would be better to do the join on an ID instead of a name (if possible).

Maybe this question will help:
[Linq-to-SQL ToDictionary()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245168/linq-to-sql-todictionary)

Comment: how to assign to this dic Dictionary<string, Privilege> becoz i want to return a s a dic..